# How to obtain the current language in a controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Here is my locale configuration

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

When I try to call locale in a controller using

```
@RequestMapping(value = "customers/customer-{idCustomer:[0-9]+}/detail", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView detail(Map<String, Object> map, @PathVariable Integer idCustomer, Locale locale) {
    logger.info(locale.toString());
    logger.info(request.getLocale().toString());
    ...
}
```

It returns different values. But when I switch a language on a site using GET param in URL `?lang=en`, it change nothing in mentioned controller's calls. i18n works fine, it loads a labels from correct file. But I want to obtain changed language in my controllers. I want to obtain choosed language independently on opened page (with/without request param `lang` in URL).

Comment: `lang=en` is just a Request Parameter. Use `@RequestParam`.

Comment: Yes, but the variable `lang` won't be availaible on a page without this request param.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `LocaleContextHolder` class that Spring provides for this purpose. From documentation:

> **Used as a central holder for the current Locale in Spring**, wherever
>   necessary: for example, in MessageSourceAccessor. DispatcherServlet
>   automatically exposes its current Locale here. Other applications can
>   expose theirs too, to make classes like MessageSourceAccessor
>   automatically use that Locale.

Then in your controller just call:

```
LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
```

to retrieve the locale using Spring.

[LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html#getLocale%28%29) javadoc.